SQL query runs much slower when add additional line to WHERE clause
I have a simple query that runs MUCH slower when I add an additional line to the WHERE clause.  I'm using SQL Server 2022 Express (v16.0.4120.1).
Query 1 (takes 15 seconds or more to run):
SELECT 
    HSP.ServiceProviderID AS SP, *
FROM 
    ALPCensus
LEFT JOIN 
    ALPPriorApproval PA ON PA.SSNumber = ALPCensus.SSNumber  
LEFT JOIN 
    ALPHeader ON ALPHeader.PartnerID = PA.PartnerID
LEFT JOIN 
    HomeServiceProviders HSP ON HSP.ServiceProviderID = ALPHeader.ServiceProviderID
LEFT JOIN 
    HomeMastResident HMR ON HMR.SSNumber = ALPCensus.SSNumber  
WHERE 
    [Day] BETWEEN PA.StartDate AND PA.EndDate
    AND [Day] < '2024-05-21'
    AND PA.IsPending = 0
    AND HSP.IsCapitation = 0
    AND [Status] IN ('*', 'P')
    AND Billed = 0
    AND HSP.ServiceProviderID =  136   -- This is the line missing from Query #2

Query 2 (same as previous query, but without the last line. Takes less than a second to run):
SELECT 
    HSP.ServiceProviderID AS SP, *
FROM 
    ALPCensus
LEFT JOIN 
    ALPPriorApproval PA ON PA.SSNumber = ALPCensus.SSNumber  
LEFT JOIN 
    ALPHeader ON ALPHeader.PartnerID = PA.PartnerID
LEFT JOIN 
    HomeServiceProviders HSP ON HSP.ServiceProviderID = ALPHeader.ServiceProviderID
LEFT JOIN 
    HomeMastResident HMR ON HMR.SSNumber = ALPCensus.SSNumber  
WHERE 
    [Day] BETWEEN PA.StartDate AND PA.EndDate
    AND [Day] < '2024-05-21'
    AND PA.IsPending = 0
    AND HSP.IsCapitation = 0
    AND [Status] IN ('*', 'P')
    AND Billed = 0

Here is an execution plan for Query 1:
Slow Query
And here is the plan for Query 2:
Fast Query
These are my database settings (if that makes a difference):
Database Settings
If I set the line to AND HSP.ServiceProviderID IS NOT NULL it also runs fast. I checked to make sure the column HSP.ServiceProviderID was of type int and not some funky data type.
Server that I'm running on seems to have plenty of CPU and RAM resources. I believe I have all the necessary indexes I need.
Edit: I noticed that if I change the SQL compatibility level to 2008 or 2012 the query runs almost instantaneously again.  Why????
Original Query using 2012 compatibility mode

Please use "Paste The Plan" to include an execution plan instead of an images which is hard to read.

You're doing SELECT * which means it's going to have to read every column of every referenced table every time, so even if you have necessary covering INDEX objects for the JOIN and WHERE clauses, it's still going to have to read all of those columns from the main table row store. Only select the columns that you actually need.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. That includes execution plans, which can be obtained as text and copy/pasted here.

I also recommend that you alias all table references and qualify all column references with those table-aliases for readability. Unqualified column references like [Day], Status and Billed give us no clue as to which table is being referenced. (I could suggest indexes that would likely fix your performance issues, if only I knew which tables contained these columns.)

(1) Use Paste the Plan to upload your execution plans, not images (which are barely readable and don't show details). (2) Post all indexes definitions for your tables - especially those that support foreign key references and join conditions. (Based on the posted images, you might not even have any indexes, which would likely be the root of your problem.) (3) Several of your WHERE conditions are effectively changing your LEFT JOINs into inner-joins. Likely not a significant contributor to performance problems, but worth noting.

If you are exclusively looking for HSP.ServiceProviderID =  136 AND HSP.IsCapitation = 0  why not just use an inner join on the HSP table?

Updated post with "Paste The Plan" links

FYI: Even when omitting the SELECT * it still runs extremely slowly

Note change to query after modifying compatibility level

There's a lot of LEFT JOIN in the query. Is this on purpose? Your WHERE clause renders these outer joins mere inner joins, because in an outer joined row IsCapitation = 0 is never true for instance as all columns are null.

As to the problem: It seems the DBMS is somehow mistaken about your data. Seeing AND HSP.ServiceProviderID =  136 it thinks it knows a faster approach to get the data, but is wrong. Let's say for instance there is an index on the column and the DBMS thinks that there are just very few rows with ServiceProviderID =  136, when it fact the table is just flooded with them. It will use that index when it shouldn't and thus get a poor performance. Maybe you need to update table statistics, to make the DBMS know your data again.

On a side note: When working with more than one table in a query, qualify all columns. Which table does [Day] belong to? Which table does [Status] belongto? Which table does Billed belong to?

Based on a manual analysis or your query and execution plans, I believe the following indexes (or equivalents) are needed to support your foreign key references and joins: ALPCensus(Day) INCLUDE(Billed, Status), ALPCensus(SSNumber, Day) INCLUDE(Billed, Status), ALPPriorApproval(SSNumber) INCLUDE(IsPending), ALPPriorApproval(PartnerID) INCLUDE(IsPending), ALPHeader(PartnerID), ALPHeader(ServiceProviderID), and HomeMastResident(SSNumber) INCLUDE(IsCapitation). (continued...)

(...continued) Some of these suggested indexes support the query plan with the HSP.ServiceProviderID =  136 condition, and some support the plan without that condition. I suggest that you check to see whether or not these indexes or equivalents are already present, and add them if they are not.  The INCLUDE(...) columns are optional, but will support some additional filtering of data before the actual table row is retrieved. If you prefer, they can be omitted or added to the end of the indexed columns, if that is your preference. The critical part of the index is the indexed column(s).
